# Extract string using #, | and % delimiters into a HTML table using PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a variable with delimiters. I have three countries `CountryA, CountryB & CountryC.`
The first delimiter is the `#` which specifies the start and end of the Country name.
The second delimiter is the `|` pipe. So under each country, we there is a set of data separated individually by the pipe.
The third delimiter is the `%` which specifies the end of each set of data above.

```
$sample="CountryA#Test1|101|Test2|%Test0|220|Test3|%#CountryB#Test4|103|Test5|%
Test6|400|Test7|%Test8|500|Test9|%#CountryC#TestA|230|TestB|%";
```

The above variable organized looks like this:

```
CountryA#
         Test1|101|Test2|%
         Test0|220|Test3|%
#CountryB#
         Test4|103|Test5|%
         Test6|400|Test7|%
         Test8|500|Test9|%
#CountryC#
         TestA|230|TestB|%
```

The delimiters `#,| and %` help identify where each data starts and ends. In the country, the first element does not have a starting # because it's not important. The subsequent countries have a starting and closing # to help identify where the country name is.

Objective:

[image: Output - Image]

I tried using explode # to first get the country names before wrapping them inside html tags but nothing happens.

```
$pieces = explode("#", $sample);
foreach($pieces as $value){
    return $value . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Use `echo` instead of `return`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why *nothing happens* with your code is because you're using `return`, which is used by functions to return a result, while I assume you wanted to use `echo` to print the `$value`. So the first thing to note is that your initial code would output something if you correctly use `echo`.

Nevertheless, due to the complexity of the type of string you're trying to parse, exploding by # might not be the best choice, as you would have the country name separated from its child nodes.

I would suggest instead to use `preg_match_all` to divide the initial `$sample` into pieces, each containing all the info of a single country.

Like this:

```
preg_match_all('@[A-z]+\#[^\#]+@', $sample, $countries);
```

This would return in `$countries[0]` an array containing 3 elements, each with all the data of each country. For example the first array would contain

```
CountryA#Test1|101|Test2|%Test0|220|Test3|%
```

Once you have this array, you can then explode first by `%`, then by `|` to obtain the remaining elements.

The full code to parse is

```
preg_match_all('@[A-z]+\#[^\#]+@', $sample, $countries);
$results = [];
foreach ($countries[0] as $c) {
    $c = explode("#", $c);
    $country_name = $c[0];
    $results[$country_name] = [];
    $params = explode("%", $c[1]);
    foreach ($params as $param_line) {
        if (!$param_line) {
            continue;
        }
        $results[$country_name][] = explode("|", trim($param_line, '|'));
    }
}
```

The `$results` array contains a multi-dimentional array with all the info divided by country and attributes, like this:

```
array(3) {
  ["CountryA"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "Test1"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "101"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "Test2"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "Test0"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "220"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "Test3"
    }
  }
  ["CountryB"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "Test4"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "103"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "Test5"
    }
```

Finally, if you want to translate this array into an HTML table similar to the one you show in your example, you can simply loop the `$results` array by 3 levels and print the results. Here's a sample

```
<table width="500">
<?php
foreach ($results as $country_name => $params) {
    ?>
    <tr><th colspan="3" style="text-align:center"><?=$country_name ?></th></tr>
    <?php foreach ($params as $param_line) {?>
    <tr>
        <td width="33%" style="text-align: center;"><?=$param_line[0] ?></td>
        <td width="33%" style="text-align: center;"><?=$param_line[1] ?></td>
        <td width="33%" style="text-align: center;"><?=$param_line[2] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php }?>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Which will output this:

[image]

Comment: Exemplary answer.

Comment: Ran into a challenge. Tried to add support for a hyphen and a space. I used ```'@[A-z0-9\s-]+\#[^\#]+@'``` which should work but the issue it that I am doing this inside WordPress and it's stripping it off of the backslash that's before the s- upon saving. So in order to save with the \ in place, I'm having to add double backslashes instead of one. After saving, one remains and on saving again, the second one disappears. So to keep the one backslash in place, I have to add two, save once and stop saving again. I am not sure why this strange behavior is happening.